# GitHub actions - adding to issue title breaking with backticks

Tags: github-actions

Take the following GitHub action:

```
name: Appends "UPDATED" to specified issue's title
  
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      NAME:
        type: string


jobs:
  update-issue:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/github-script@v6.4.1
        with:
          script: |
            const newTitle = `$${{ github.event.inputs.NAME }} - UPDATED`
            github.issues.update({
              issue_number: `1`,
              owner: `user`,
              repo: `my-repo`,
              title: newTitle
            })
```

When run with a regular input, it works fine - but when the issue title (substituted for `NAME` to run more easily) contains a backtick, a `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` is thrown.

Example to reproduce locally using [act](https://github.com/nektos/act):

```
act -j update-issue -v -s GITHUB_TOKEN="$(gh auth token)" -e payload.json
```

`payload.json`:

```
{
  "inputs": {
    "NAME": "`V`"
  }
}
```

I think what's happening is that the substitution happens first, causing the following:

```
name: Appends "UPDATED" to specified issue's title
  
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      NAME:
        type: string


jobs:
  update-issue:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/github-script@v6.4.1
        with:
          script: |
            const newTitle = ``V` - UPDATED`
            github.issues.update({
              issue_number: `1`,
              owner: `user`,
              repo: `my-repo`,
              title: newTitle
            })
```

And the `` are confusing things.

Is there a way to work around this? Or another way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Can you try with "NAME": "\\`V\\`" in payload.json?. ie, escape with slash?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM the input can’t be changed - in the real world it’s the GitHub issue name, which is accessed directly via an environment variable.

Comment: I understood, but wanted to know if that's the problem. If yes you probably have to use the double quotes to denote the string(`newTitle `) in JS

Comment: Can you set the title in an environment variable, and then reference that variable instead? Using `${{...}}` directly is vulnerable to injections.

Comment: @BenjaminW. i've tried that, but it hasn't addressed the problem? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your immediate issue, you don't need backticks: `${{...}}` is expanded before anything else.

Also, notice that you're missing `.rest` for `github.rest.issues.update`, but I assume that's a copy-paste error.

This would work if `NAME` contains backticks:

```yaml
      - uses: actions/github-script@v6.4.1
        with:
          script: |
            const newTitle = '${{ github.event.inputs.NAME }} - UPDATED';
```

However, this breaks if `NAME` contains a single quote, and it's still vulnerable to [script injection](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#understanding-the-risk-of-script-injections).

A better approach is to set the value in the environment first:

```yaml
      - uses: actions/github-script@v6.4.1
        env:
          name: ${{ github.event.inputs.NAME }}
        with:
          script: |
            const newTitle = process.env.name + ' - UPDATED';
```

This works for any string.

Or, alternatively, you could use the GitHub CLI in a `run` step instead of using github-script:

```yaml
      - env:
          name: ${{ github.event.inputs.NAME }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
        run: |
          gh issue edit --repo "$GITHUB_REPOSITORY" 1 --title "$name - UPDATED"
```